# Which sentence structure is more correct and why?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Ich finde den Bauernhof gehen is besser als den Berg klettern.

Vs.

> Ich finde, auf den Bauernhof zu gehen ist besser als auf den Berg zu klettern.

I can understand using auf with berg ..to indicate the top of the mountain but why with Bauernhof?

About using zu is it a must to make the sentence correct ?

Comment: "Is besser" geht auf Hochdeutsch auch nicht. In mündlicher Rede, Straßenjargon isses aber verbreitet. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence makes no sense at all, a kind of *literally* translation would be:

> I find go the farm...

`Auf` has several meanings, among them there are:

- on
- upon
- to
- at
- to
- in

Some examples of this:

> Auf dem Baum (in the tree)
>
> auf der Erde (on earth)
>
> auf dem Hügel (on the hill)
>
> auf einem Pferd sitzen (to sit on/upon a horse)
>
> warst du schon auf der Polizei? (have you already been to the police)
>
> auf Gleis 3 (at platform 3)
>
> auf Jamaika (in Jamaica)
>
> auf dem Bauernhof (at the farm)
>
> auf den Bauernhof (to the farm)

Prepositions in german are usually very difficult when learning. I recommend you to try to remember in which cases you use which preposition, it's a long way but with practice you will get better.

You use `zu` to bind the verb, it's kind of the english `to`:

> Ich muss verstehen was ich lese, um es den anderen **zu** erklären (I have to understand what I'm reading in order **to** explain it to the others)

Answer (score 1):

1. "zu" is necessary for a correct sentence.
2. The preposition "auf" is necessary as well."gehen" is not a transitive verb with an object, it needs a prepositional adjunct.
3. As for "Why 'auf'?", this is to a large part arbitrary. "Hof" takes "auf" and that's all there's to it, it's a bit of agreement that you have to learn just like gender and number agreement. Compare a bird on a branch in German and English: the English bird sits *in* a tree, but a German bird would sit *on* (auf) a tree, but clearly this says something about differences between the two languages, and not about differences in the situation.

Comment: Perhaps the answer would benefit for explaining *why* zu is needed to make the sentence correct, since that's exactly what the OP seems to be struggling with